# Map arrays to objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I am trying to map two arrays to an array of objects. I want to map this

```
let indices = [1,2,3,4];
let values = [11,21,2,4];
```

to this

```
let data = [{
    indices: 1,
    value: 10,
}, {
    indices: 2,
    value: 20,
}, {
    indices: 3,
    value: 30,
}, {
    indices: 4,
    value: 50,
}];
```

I tried a lot but can't find any proper way to implement this. Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: why dont you use a traditional for loop?

Comment: I've edited your question to remove all mention of JSON. Your question has no JSON in it. These are just plain old arrays and plain old objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I map over two arrays at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311322/how-can-i-map-over-two-arrays-at-the-same-time)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `values` array? You don't seem be using any of them in your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `map` like so:

```js
let indices = [1,2,3,4];
let values = [11,21,2,4];
let data = values.map((e, i) => ({ indices: indices[i], value: e }));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: This doesn't match the desired output, however I'm inclined to believe that your answer is right and OP's desired output is wrong.

Comment: @TylerRoper Yes - I believe they replaced their `values`s' values with different values.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an objects with the key for the wanted keys and the values and iterate the entries and their values for mapping a new array.

```js
function getArray(object) {
    return Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce(
            (r, [k, array]) => array.map((v, i) => Object.assign({}, r[i], { [k]: v })),
            []
        );
}

var index = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    value = [11, 21, 2, 4],
    result = getArray({ index, value });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```